# Dynamic jQuery selector through a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I loop through a set of numbers to target my elements? Eg.

```
    for ( i = 1; i < 9; i++ ) {
        $( 'myPetal'+i ).myX = 500;
        $( 'myPetal'+i ).myY = 500;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a list of elements you are trying to iterate over?  You might not need to loop at all.

Comment: You are selecting  `<myPetal1>` elements.... I highly doubt you have elements.

Comment: Yea sorry, my bad, it's supposed to be .myPetal... Thanks for highlighting it!

Comment: This is an XY Problem. What exactly are you trying to do? Have you actually run any of this code? Your comments on the answers suggest that you have not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget in in jQuery you still need selectors:

For IDs you would do

```
 for ( var i = 1; i < 9; i++ ) {
      $( '#myPetal'+i ).myX = 500;
      $( '#myPetal'+i ).myY = 500;
 }
```

And for classes

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 9; i++ ) {
         $( '.myPetal'+i ).myX = 500;
         $( '.myPetal'+i ).myY = 500;
    }
```

Your code sample would look for `<myPetal[i]>` in the DOM.

Comment: Anything you put between `$(` and `).*` will concatenate just like anything else in javascript

Comment: Also, you need to initialize `i` as a variable - I edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: Hey Mark, I realised you can't directly add a variable myX to the element. It doesn't register. How do I add variables to elements like that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code? `$().myX` and `.myY` are not valid jQuery functions.  If you are trying to set height and width, you would instead use:
`$( '.myPetal'+i ).height(500);
$( '.myPetal'+i ).width(500);`

If you are trying to manipulate css properties you could use
`$( '.myPetal'+i ).css( "propertyName", "value" );`

Comment: Hmm.. Basically, I'm trying to add properties to each element so that I can use it later on. I'm not going to set or manipulate anything right away, just storing variables.

Comment: @KelvinZhao `$( foo )` represents a DOM object, as in an HTML element.  Since jQuery is written in Javascript (which is a scripting language), you don't have to initialize variables as you do in other languages such as Java.  If you're trying to create an object to store data in, then this is **not** the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the loop and instead use the prefix `myPetal` in the query to get all elements that has a class that starts with that value:

```
$("*[class^='myPetal']").attr('myY', 500);
```

Same idea could be applied in case of using other attributes

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could do that! But I realised you can't directly add attributes like that too. =( Have to go through some other way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.class1').attr('myX', 500);
$('.class1').attr('myY', 500);
$('.class1').html('myX : '+$('.class1').attr('myX') + ' myY : '+$('.class1').attr('myY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">class1</div>
<div class="class1">class1</div>
<div class="class1">class1</div>
```

if you have the same class for the elements and the value you want to add is same you can do it this way, or you can loop it using .each() function like this

```
$('.class1').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('myX', 500);
   $(this).attr('myY', 500);
})
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! That's what I was looking for.